# HttpPost с параметрами

Tags: android

Хочу получить координаты `lat` и `lng` по этой ссылке http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=

Отправляю запрос следующим образом:

```
private InputStream retrieveStreamLatLng(String url){

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        String address = placeEditText.getText().toString();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpPost);

        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode
                    + " for URL " + url);
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        return getResponseEntity.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        httpPost.abort();
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Это не первый запрос в моей жизни. Но так вот в этом запросе параметр адреса не присваивается. Если я руками вбиваю `url` с адресом, то работает, а в таком виде и ошибок не выдаёт и страница с нулевыми результатами приходит, т.е. параметр адреса вообще отсутствует.

```
   public static final String latLngUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true";  - url который передаётся методу в параметре.
```

А здесь я получаю ответ

```
InputStream source = retrieveStreamLatLng(config.latLngUrl);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            try{
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);...
```

Comment: попробуйте сделать передаваемый url"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json

Comment: пробовала) но не прокатило)